# How to handle ListView Item LongPress gesture

Tags: android, android-listview, android-event, android-gesture

i have small issues in event handling , i have List view  custom adapter data , each row having date , title , price . when i click on row i need to display details page but when i long press on price , date or title i need to sort the list view. i need to use gesture for on Long Press. please refer below code what i have tried.

Custom Adapter View

```
public EventAdapterView(Context context, List<EventUtil> eventList) {

        this.mContext = context;
        this.mEventUtil = eventList;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new DrawableManager();

    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        mView = convertView;
        EventUtil eventUtil = mEventUtil.get(position);

        mView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_event_adapter, null);

        TextView eventTitleView = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.list_view_event_title);
        TextView eventDescView = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.list_view_event_location);
        TextView eventDateView = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.list_view_event_price);

        // final MyGestureDetector myGestureDetector= new MyGestureDetector();

        // new ImageFeach().execute(mEventUtil.getEvent_Image_Url());

        eventTitleView.setText(eventUtil.getEvent_Title());

        // event title sorting

        eventTitleView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                new MyGestureDetector() {

                    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event1) {

                        //if (event1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            Collections.sort(mEventUtil,
                                    new Comparator<EventUtil>() {

                                        @Override
                                        public int compare(EventUtil obje1,
                                                EventUtil obje2) {

                                            return obje1
                                                    .getEvent_Title()
                                                    .compareTo(
                                                            obje2.getEvent_Title());
                                        }

                                    });

                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //}

                    };

                }.onLongPress(event);

                return true;
            }
        });

        // event location sorting
        eventDescView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                new MyGestureDetector() {

                    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event1) {

                        //if (event1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            Collections.sort(mEventUtil,
                                    new Comparator<EventUtil>() {

                                        @Override
                                        public int compare(EventUtil event1,
                                                EventUtil event2) {

                                            return event1
                                                    .getEvent_location()
                                                    .compareTo(
                                                            event2.getEvent_location());
                                        }

                                    });
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //}

                    };

                }.onLongPress(event);

                return true;
            }
        });

        // event price sorting
        eventDateView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                new MyGestureDetector() {

                    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event1) {

                    //  if (event1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            Collections.sort(mEventUtil,
                                    new Comparator<EventUtil>() {

                                        @Override
                                        public int compare(EventUtil event1,
                                                EventUtil event2) {

                                            return event1
                                                    .getEvent_Price()
                                                    .compareTo(
                                                            event2.getEvent_Price());
                                        }

                                    });
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //}

                    };

                }.onLongPress(event);

                return true;
            }
        });

        // event date sorting
        ImageView dateImageView = (ImageView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.list_view_event_date);

        dateImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                new MyGestureDetector() {

                    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event1) {

                        //if (event1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            Collections.sort(mEventUtil,
                                    new Comparator<EventUtil>() {

                                        @Override
                                        public int compare(EventUtil event1,
                                                EventUtil event2) {

                                            return event2
                                                    .getEvent_Date()
                                                    .compareTo(
                                                            event1.getEvent_Date());
                                        }
                                    });
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //}

                    };

                }.onLongPress(event);


                return true;
            }
        });
```

MyGestureDetector Class

```
public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

        super.onLongPress(e);
    }



}
```

Help Me.. Thanks

Comment: So what happening?? Any error occurred??

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using the `ListView` method for long press? `onItemLongClickListener`

Comment: @Neil I think user wants to implement `onItemLongClickListener` on every element of `ListView`.

Comment: Yeah but that is what the onItemLongClickListener is for. Look at @Dhaval's answer

Comment: Since the question is asked only about LongClick on Row only, my answer is correct. Your answer @shree202, is however right if we want elements of row to have such a listener. Cheerio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, there's no need to use `SimpleOnGestureListener`.

In your Custom Adapter View:

First,

```
eventTitleView.setFocusable(false); 
eventTitleView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
eventTitleView.setLongClickable(true);

eventDescView.setFocusable(false); 
eventDescView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
eventDescView.setLongClickable(true);

eventDateView.setFocusable(false); 
eventDateView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
eventDateView.setLongClickable(true);
```

Then,
just set `setOnLongClickListener (View.OnLongClickListener l)` on `eventTitleView`, `eventDescView` and `eventDateView` as,

```
eventTitleView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //do your sorting stuff here
        }
    });

eventDescView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //do your sorting stuff here
        }
    });

eventDateView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //do your sorting stuff here
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to override onlongpress?

You know this function is available by default right?

just put the price , date or title on the same Layout and give each one OnLongPressListener with the action you want..:

EXAMPLE: 
http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/

Answer (score 0):

```
 ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // YOUR SORTING CODE HERE

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: but i need to handle onItemClick Listener and then i need to perfrom individual view OnLong Press like price longPress , date Long Press then i need to perform sorting

Comment: According to your question, you need to sort the list on LongClick. Then this is where you put your sorting code. If you apply onCLickListener, then how on earth would you stay on ListView Activity to perform LongClick if you are Lauching another details activity?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this thro `onLongClickListener`. It's easy using this interface . You need to do

```
Class YourClass implements onLongClickListener{

 public boolean onLongClick(View arg0){                                 

 // Event generated when user have long pressed the screen

  return false; // If you do not want the event to keep occuring again and again

}
```